# what format distanceTo function returns in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

i am using distanceTo function in OpenLayers Geometry.

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.distanceTo

here am confused in which format it will return the value. It is in Kilometers or meters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Meters if your map units are in meters (default).</strike>

## Correction:

Sorry, default is degrees.
[map units documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.units)

> Defaults to ‘degrees’.  Possible values are ‘degrees’ (or ‘dd’), ‘m’,
>   ‘ft’, ‘km’, ‘mi’, ‘inches’.

But you can change that in your map constructor:

```js
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    units: 'm'
});
```

You can get the units like this:

```js
map.getUnits();
```

Comment: I was wrong, please see my update.